# Active Directory Web Service Keeps Crashing

Tags: active-directory

ADWS was working fine yesterday, however this morning I logged in and it kept crashing. After crashing, it throws the 1067 error for around 2 hours.

I checked the warnings in event viewer, and it stated
" There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper. "

As i said, it was working perfectly fine yesterday, however today it's just being a pain.

Could anybody help?

Comment: `After crashing, it throws the 1067 error for around 2 hours` - It's doubtful that anyone knows what Event ID 1067 is off the top of their head and it's even more doubtful that anyone is going to take the time to go look it up just for the purpose of answering your question, so how about you include the details of that Event ID in your question?

Comment: 0x42b (WIN32: 1067 ERROR_PROCESS_ABORTED) -- 1067 (1067)
Error message text: The process terminated unexpectedly.  If the other message about "no more endpoints" is related, could you be running out of ephemeral ports? Event ID 4231? Does this help - https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln249100/windows-server-you-receive-a-no-more-endpoints-available-error-when-trying-to-join-a-domain?lang=en